# How to export currency exchange from metatrader?

Tags: xml, json, export, metatrader4, metatrader5

I'm lookin for a solution, how to export currency exchange from metatrader (4 or 5)
to web (json, csv, xml...)

I saw that it is possible export to excel file.

Answer (score 1):

## Online soft-RealTime export

MT4 can serve as `anEventFACTORY` process and send live-Quote(s) aka "Tick(s)" to further processing, be it internal ( via a function call ) or external ( via a ZeroMQ or nanomsg communication framework )

### Architecture

MT4 has a default internal EventLOOP that triggers `int start(){ <_code-block_> }` upon each Quote arrival in both *Expert Advisor* and *Custom Indicator*. Besides that a *Script* can handle Quote arrivals on it's own near-RT loop with a use of `bool RefreshRates()`

### Time Resolution

MT4 has rather a poor TimeDOMAIN resolution and can work down to about **1 msec** via `int GetTickCount()`

### Do-s & Don't-s

MT4 cannot run more than **one** *Expert Advisor* **+ one** *Script* **+ a few** *Custom Indicators* per `MT4.Graph`

MT4 threading is rather a fragile fabric to build any high-workload software

MT4 code inside MQL4 can block the whole "receiving engine" of the MT4 ( not speaking about `MT4.TradingCONTEXT` ... , so be carefull and place reasonable `void Sleep( int msecs2sleep )` where not in an RT-sensitive part of any code.

### Beware of Blocking

MT4 `fileIO` blocks, avoid as much as possible and if pressed to, cache and deferr disk write(s) to situations, where you are sure to have 15-40 msec "free-time" to rest in a `fileIO-blocked` <*code-block*> execution <**state**>. While this may seem funny on a first sight, this may hang your `MT4` platform if you happen to arrange such "*export*" processing in a poor manner and `MT4` threading model get beyond their MUTEX/LOCKs resilience treshold.

### Does it sound like building a RealTime Software inside MetaTrader?

Yes.

Correct.

### Verba docent. Exempla trahunt.

Try to use such an approach to use a **thin-soft-RT-client** inside MT4 and either cache-writes as [MQL4 RT-scanners TAMARA & SONAR do](http://jonathan.mach.sweb.cz/DEMO/FxTOOLS_DEMO.html), where you will see, that it soon takes several minutes (**MINUTES**) of a `sustained-fileIO-write`-s to store just a few majors on `localhost` disk ... , or better -- distribute locally collected data-chunks to a remote `loggerPROCESS` ( **syslog** alike ) or any other { online | offline } post-processing

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EA to do that. I personally collect the rates (every tick) and push to an SQL server. Pushing to an SQL server is more tricky (I use a custom DLL to do that). But you can easily just append it to a csv or tab-delimited file.  This will give you a tab-delimited file which you can import into Excel. But be warned that this can get really huge.  Also, although there is a time element in there, the `TimeCurrent()` is accurate to the second only. To get accuracy down to milisecond, you will need something more tricky.  But the rates will be appended in sequence.

```
int start()     {
    logRates();
    return(0);
}

void logRates( string pvsSymbol, double pviAsk, double pviBid ) {
    string  vsFilename  = "Rates (" + Symbol() + ") " + Month() + "-" + Day() + ".txt";
    int     handle      = FileOpen(vsFilename + ".txt", FILE_CSV|FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE, '\t');
    if(handle>0) {
        FileSeek(handle, 0, SEEK_END);
        FileWrite(handle, TimeCurrent(), pvsSymbol, pviBid, pviAsk);
        FileClose(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok , if I'll export 10 pairs to csv one and same file in every second. is it possible to read that file every second ?

Comment: yes you can. but in general, it is better to split each ccy to its own file.

Comment: @Joseph logging is possible, however at a cost of immense `fileIO` overhead, which makes it unusable in production-grade environment. Much better approach is to use a **thin-soft-RT-client** inside MT4 and either cache-writes as [MQL4 RT-scanners TAMARA & SONAR do](http://jonathan.mach.sweb.cz/DEMO/FxTOOLS_DEMO.html), where one should # **be aware** #, that it takes several minutes (**MINUTES**) of a `sustained-fileIO-write`-s to store just a few majors on disk ... , or distribute data-chunks to a remote logger ( **syslog** alike ) or even dispatch these to JSON or whatever forward processing